# How to make four-way logarithmic plot in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Four-way logarithmic plot is a very often used graph for vibration control and earthquake protection. I am quite interesting in how this plot can be plotted in Matplotlib instead of adding axes in Inkscape. A sample of Four-way logarithmic plot is here.

[image: Four-way logarithmic plot]

A quick and dirty Python code can generate main part of the figure, but I cannot add the two axes onto the figure. http://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/demo_curvelinear_grid.html provides an example of adding axes, but I fails to make it working. Anyone has similar experience on adding axes to Matplotlib figure?

```
from pylab import *
from  mpl_toolkits.axisartist.grid_helper_curvelinear import GridHelperCurveLinear
from mpl_toolkits.axisartist import Subplot
beta=logspace(-1,1,500)
Rd={}
for zeta in [0.01,0.1,0.2,0.7,1]:
    Rd[zeta]=beta/sqrt((1-beta*beta)**2+(2*beta*zeta)**2)
    loglog(beta,Rd[zeta])
ylim([0.1,10])
xlim([0.1,10])
grid('on',which='minor')
```

[image: my plot]

Update: Thank you all! I use Inkscape to modify the figure above. I think the result is just fine. However, I am still looking for methods to draw this figure in Matplotlib.
[image: Inkscape Modified]

Comment: are you looking to generate that specific figure, or are you looking to plot data and get this kind of output (style of tick labels, gridlines, range of the axes, text labels on the diagonal axis ticks, etc...), or are you looking for something that automagically makes a nice looking plot for whatever the data you happen to plot?

Comment: I am looking for ways that how to manipulate axes, ticks and labels freely. I am not so happy with axes produced by Matplotlib by default, especially Axes3D. Actually, I asked a question about 3D axes in Matplotlib, it seems no one is interested in that topic. This question is just an example of manipulate axes in Matplotlib.

Comment: In the context of this question, were you hoping to use the extra axes for plotting?

Comment: Yes, from last year's pycon, I see they are playing with the axes. Therefore, I think I can make it work, too. But it still very tricky to get theose things done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a partial solution.  I am still working on how to do all of this in a natural `loglog()` plot rather than scaling the data.  (To complete this example you would have to define custom tick-lables so that they display `10**x` rather than `x`.)

```
%matplotlib inline                   # I am doing this in an IPython notebook.
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy import log10

# Generate the data
beta = np.logspace(-1, 1, 500)[:, None]
zeta = np.array([0.01,0.1,0.2,0.7,1])[None, :]
Rd = beta/np.sqrt((1 - beta*beta)**2 + (2*beta*zeta)**2)

def draw(beta=beta, Rd=Rd):
    plt.plot(log10(beta), log10(Rd))
    plt.ylim([log10(0.1), log10(10)])
    plt.xlim([log10(0.1), log10(10)])
    plt.grid('on',which='minor')
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.set_aspect(1)

from mpl_toolkits.axisartist import GridHelperCurveLinear
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D
from mpl_toolkits.axisartist import SubplotHost
from mpl_toolkits.axisartist import Subplot

#tr = Affine2D().rotate(-np.pi/2)
#inv_tr = Affine2D().rotate(np.pi/2)

class Transform(object):
    """Provides transforms to go to and from rotated grid.

    Parameters
    ----------
    ilim : (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
       The limits of the displayed axes (in physical units)
    olim : (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
       The limits of the rotated axes (in physical units)
    """
    def __init__(self, ilim, olim):
        # Convert each to a 3x3 matrix and compute the transform
        # [x1, y1, 1] = A*[x0, y0, 1]
        x0, x1, y0, y1 = np.log10(ilim)
        I = np.array([[x0, x0, x1],
                      [y0, y1, y1],
                      [ 1,  1,  1]])

        x0, x1, y0, y1 = np.log10(olim)
        x_mid = (x0 + x1)/2
        y_mid = (y0 + y1)/2
        O = np.array([[   x0, x_mid, x1],
                      [y_mid,    y1, y_mid],
                      [    1,     1,     1]])
        self.A = np.dot(O, np.linalg.inv(I))
        self.Ainv = np.linalg.inv(self.A)

    def tr(self, x, y):
        """From "curved" (rotated) coords to rectlinear coords"""
        x, y = map(np.asarray, (x, y))
        return np.dot(self.A, np.asarray([x, y, 1]))[:2]

    def inv_tr(self, x, y):
        """From rectlinear coords to "curved" (rotated) coords"""
        x, y = map(np.asarray, (x, y))
        return np.dot(self.Ainv, np.asarray([x, y, 1]))[:2]

ilim = (0.1, 10)
olim = (0.01, 100)
tr = Transform(ilim + ilim, olim + olim)

grid_helper = GridHelperCurveLinear((tr.tr, tr.inv_tr))

fig = plt.gcf()
ax0 = Subplot(fig, 1, 1, 1)
ax1 = Subplot(fig, 1, 1, 1, grid_helper=grid_helper, frameon=False)
ax1.set_xlim(*np.log10(olim))
ax1.set_ylim(*np.log10(olim))
ax1.axis["left"] = ax1.new_floating_axis(0, 0.)
ax1.axis["bottom"] = ax1.new_floating_axis(1, 0.0)
fig.add_subplot(ax0)
fig.add_subplot(ax1)
ax0.grid('on', which='both')
ax1.grid('on', which='both')

plt.plot(log10(beta), log10(Rd))
plt.ylim(np.log10(ilim))
plt.xlim(np.log10(ilim))
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bit tricker than it should.  There are ways to center the spines (axis lines), and ways to rotate them, but those do not work together.  Adding a normal axis on a line (a la mpl demos) results in a curved axis (because it is logarithmic).  Here is a [poor] example of how to draw -- as in, like you would with Inkscape something to look like an additional pair of axis spines with the example data.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#data
b = np.logspace(-1, 1, 500)
Rd = {}
for zeta in [0.01, 0.1, 0.2, 0.7, 1]:
    Rd[zeta] = b / np.sqrt((1 - b * b) ** 2 + (2 * b * zeta) ** 2)

#plot
fig = plt.figure()   
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

for z in Rd:  
    ax1.loglog(b, Rd[z])

ax1.set_xlim([0.1, 10])
ax1.set_ylim([0.1, 10])
ax1.set_aspect(1.)

#draw lines to look like diagonal spines (axes)
xmin, xmax = ax1.get_xlim()  # xlim == ylim

a = np.log10(xmin)
b = np.log10(xmax)
span = b - a
period_points = 3  # number of points/ticks per decade
npts = (span * period_points) + 1  # +1 for even powers of 10
x1 = np.logspace(a, b, num=npts)
x2 = np.logspace(b, a, num=npts)

ax1.plot(x1, x1, color='k', marker='x', ms='9')
ax1.plot(x1, x2, color='k', marker='x', ms='9')
#NOTE: v1.2.1 lacks 'TICKUP' and similar - these may be
#   a better choice in v1.3x and beyond

ax1.text(0.97, 0.9,
         "axis label: A",
         size='large',
         horizontalalignment='right',
         verticalalignment='top',
         rotation=45,
         transform=ax1.transAxes,
         #bbox={'facecolor': 'white', 'alpha': 0.5, 'pad': 10},
         )

ax1.text(0.03, 0.9,
         "axis label: B",
         size='large',
         horizontalalignment='left',
         verticalalignment='top',
         rotation=-45,
         transform=ax1.transAxes,
         #bbox={'facecolor': 'white', 'alpha': 0.5, 'pad': 10},
         )

plt.savefig("example.pdf")
```

Comment: Yes, I agree. Matplotlib is still not that mature as Matlab, you will always find something working not as you expected. Maybe simply using Inkscape to add the two axes is the best the choice for this graph.

Comment: Depending on how often you create plots like this, that could be a better idea than getting a more generalized function to nicely draw the axes in matplotlib.